# AngularJS - Success is not a function

Tags: angularjs

Got this factory :

```
phonecatServices.factory('Phone', ['$resource',
 function($resource){
    return $resource('phones/:phoneId.json', {}, {
    query: {method:'GET', params:{phoneId:'phones'}, isArray:true}
  });
}]);
```

I use this service like this but got a `success is not a function` error :

```
    Phone.get({phoneId: $routeParams.phoneId}).$promise.then(
        function(data){
            ici.phone = data;
            ici.mainImageUrl = data.images[0];
        },
        function(reason){
            alert("Phone error: " + reason);
        }
    );
```

`c` is my closure.

Can you help ?

Comment: Now that you have editid your code, what is the current error you are getting?

Comment: I found the error. In fact the above code is OK, I just had an IoD in a wrong place !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.success` is not directly available when using `ngResource`. You need to use `$promise.then` or `$promise.success` to access the methods from promise. SO your updated code would look like this

```
Phone.get({phoneId: $routeParams.phoneId})
  .$promise
  .then(function(data){
        c.phone = data;
        c.mainImageUrl = data.images[0];
    });
```